# I am using Wordpress video plugin ( Contus video gallery ) want to integrate html 5 For ads

Tags: html, responsive-design, wordpress, vast

Hello i am using contus video gallery for wordpress actually the video ads are working fine on computer but i want to integrate html 5 video system as well don't know where to get started it the content video works fine on mobile but alsow ant to show an add want to integrate custom code in it ,

Comment: Contus has their own forums. They can help you.

Comment: YOu are right they wont help in the how to customize our plugin